# Fill dictionary with values from list

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, model

I have a list generated from LINQ query. An example of this list is the following

```
ID = 1, CODE = 2
ID = 1, CODE = 3
ID = 1  CODE = 4
....
```

I would like to fill a dictionary with these values to have the key of my dictionary equals to id of my list and the value like the code of my list

Wxample what I want is

`myDict = 1 : {2,3,4}`

Is it possible?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: is your list a `List<string>` or what is it? Please provide some code that shows your class-structure. It's hard to guess.

Comment: Yes its possible, what have you tried? What is the actual input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy`:

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> myDict = list
    .GroupBy(x => x.ID)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(x => x.CODE).ToList());
```

Comment: Why use `GroupBy().ToDictionary()` when `ToLookUp()` can do both things for you?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride: there is often more than one way, but OP has asked for a dictionary though

Comment: But if the list contains more than one id? The method is still the same?

Comment: @th3answer: sure, why you don't try it? ;-)

Comment: Because I'm a little bit confused, my problem now is to fill the list with the response of the query, I execute the query into a loop (because I need to cicle a list of id passed like parameter). Using .ToList() when I have ID = 2, my list is filled with data where ID = 2, and the data with ID = 1 are cancelled. Hope you will understand!

Comment: @th3answer: No, you have to show the code then. Maybe you could ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

There is a lesser known collection type called [`ILookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.ilookup-2?view=net-7.0) exactly for this purpose, i.e. map a key to multiple items. The only way to create it is via the extension method [`ToLookup()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup?view=net-7.0).

Assuming both `ID` and `CODE` are `int`s:

```cs
var lookup = yourList.ToLookup(x => x.ID, x => x.CODE);
var itemsWithId1 = lookup[1]; // contains 2, 3, 4
```

Comment: Is it possible to add another element ? To have   ID = 1 : CODE = 2,3,4 ; ID = 2 : CODE = 2,3,4

Comment: @th3answer sure, it will do that automatically for each unique value of `ID`.